# Not able to switch boxes by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 boxes and I would like to switch them by drag and drop. If you test my code, you will see that you can drag the blue box into the red box but then it stops working. When you try to set that box back, you get the error:

> Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentElement' on 'Element': parameter 2 is
> not of type 'Element'.

That is because the first parameter of the function `insertAdjacentElement()` is `beforeBegin`. I assume that the problem will be solved if there is an if statement by asking if that element is type of 'Element' (as the error says), use the parameter `beforeBegin`, otherwise use the parameter `beforeStart`.

I have tried it with the following code but I get the same error:

```
if (document.getElementById(data)) {
  element.insertAdjacentElement('beforeBegin', document.getElementById(data));
} else {
  element.insertAdjacentElement('beforeStart', document.getElementById(data));
}
```

**Full code**

```js
// Drag and the drop the items
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#title-drag, #storename-drag');

for (let element of elements) {
  // Allow the drop 
  element.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  element.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  }, false);

  element.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      element.insertAdjacentElement('beforeBegin', document.getElementById(data));

    console.log(element);
  });
}
```

```css
#title {
  background: red;
}
#storename {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Title -->
  <div class="row">
    <div id="title-drag">
      <div class="col-md-3" draggable="true" id="title">
        <div class="mg-item-inner">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container='body' title='Gibt den Seitentitel aus'>
              <span class="name">TITLE</span><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container='body' title="Linie Erweitern / Reduzieren">
              <i class="fas fa-swatchbook"></i></button>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <div class="input-group" role="group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">prefix <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">prefix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">suffix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">none</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /input-btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div><!-- /input-group --><span type="button" class="btn add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        </div><!-- /mg-item-inner -->
      </div><!-- /mg-item -->
    </div>

    <!--STORE NANE  -->
    <div id="storename-drag">
      <div class="col-md-3" draggable="true" id="storename">
        <div class="mg-item-inner">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container='body' title='Fügt den Storename hinzu'>
              <span class="name">STORENAME</span><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Linie Erweitern / Reduzieren">
              <i class="fas fa-swatchbook"></i></button>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <div class="input-group" role="group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">prefix <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">prefix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">suffix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">none</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /input-btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div><!-- /input-group --><span type="button" class="btn add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        </div><!-- /mg-item-inner -->
      </div><!-- /mg-item -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q5unvjw6/

Comment: Maybe something like this can be of help. http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/

Comment: @Alessandro thanks, but I would like to do it without using a library.